# Updating column from being NULL after action is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Stripe is setup on my app and users can cancel or upgrade their subscription. It communicates perfectly to Stripe. I need help figuring out how I can make the changes communicate with my database.

If a user cancels their subscription it should be marked in the Subscriptions table under a `cancelled` column. With this in place the user will be restricted access to website if it shows in the database that their subscription was cancelled.

I am not sure how to add this to the cancel subscription action I have setup.

Help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Subscriptions controller:

```
  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    if params[:PayerID]
      @subscription.paypal_customer_token = params[:PayerID]
      @subscription.paypal_payment_token = params[:token]
      @subscription.email = @subscription.paypal.checkout_details.email
    end
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

    def updatesubscription
      @user = current_user
      @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
      @customer.update_subscription(:plan => "1", :prorate => true)
     current_user.save!
      flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been updated!'
      redirect_to root_url
     end

     def cancelsubscription
       @user = current_user
         @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
         @customer.cancel_subscription()
         current_user.save!
         flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been cancelled successfully!'
         redirect_to root_url
       end

       def showcard
         @user = current_user
         Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token).cards.all()
       end

       def changecard
           @user = current_user       
           @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)

             card = @customer.cards.create({
               :card => @user.subscription.stripe_customer_token
             })

             @customer.default_card = card
             @customer.save
           end
end
```

Subscription model:

```
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :plan_id
  validates_presence_of :email

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token, :paypal_payment_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      if paypal_payment_token.present?
        save_with_paypal_payment
      else
        save_with_stripe_payment
      end
    end
  end

  def paypal
    PaypalPayment.new(self)
  end

  def save_with_paypal_payment
    response = paypal.make_recurring
    self.paypal_recurring_profile_token = response.profile_id
    save!
  end

  def save_with_stripe_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
    self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
    save!
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end

  def payment_provided?
    stripe_card_token.present? || paypal_payment_token.present?
  end

  def suspend_paypal
    paypal.suspend
    save
  end


  def reactivate_paypal
    paypal.reactivate
    save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be to add extra lines to update the required column.

```
def cancelsubscription
  @user = current_user
  @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
  @customer.cancel_subscription()
  current_user.subscription.update_attributes(:cancelled => 1)
  current_user.save!
  flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been cancelled successfully!'
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

However, ideally all this should happen within a model. From the controller you should just be telling the model to cancel the subscription.

So, this method could become something like:

```
#subscriptions_controller.rb
def cancelsubscription
  current_user.subscription.cancel_stripe_subscription
  flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been cancelled successfully!'
  redirect_to root_url
end

#subscription.rb model
def cancel_stripe_subscription
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(self.stripe_customer_token)
  customer.cancel_subscription()
  self.cancelled = 1
  self.save!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant you update the Subscription table via an active_record query? Like this:

```
updateQuery = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE Subscription SET cancelled = 'Cancelled' WHERE user_id = #{@user.id}")
```

That'd update your subscription table and change the targetted field value to "Cancelled". Its not clear if this is a boolean or not. If it is, then the value should be "TRUE" instead of the "Cancelled" string i put in there.

If subscription succesfully saves, then you execute the query. But you'd have to make sure you put the query between a condition so that it only executes it when the user has cancelled the subscription, not every time its updated.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @subscription.save
    if (something to tell the controller you are cancelling the subscription)
       EXECUTE QUERY HERE
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks will have to look into this some more as I am unfamiliar with using ActiveRecord in that manner. Will post update.

Comment: What's the difference between using active record query vs. callbacks?

Comment: Well, im not THAT versed in callbacks, but i'd say that the main difference between those 2 is that callbacks required an action to be take in order to trigger the event (before.save/after.save) whereas a query is more direct way to deal with the database. Im sure both have their pros and cons.

Comment: Ok that's what I was thinking while reading up on it. I would need the update to the database to take place after the subscription has been saved. I was trying to understand your code and it didn't seem like it would only update after subscription was handled. Though I don't have any experience with doing a query so I could be wrong.

Comment: You could execute this query after you evaluate whether or not the subscription was save. Check my revised answer.